# Can any one tell me what are these white cotton like substances growing on these leaves?

Tags: diseases

My chili plant leaves have these white cotton like blobs growing on them. Is this some kind of disease?
[image: leaf]
[image: leaf (same)]
[image: leaf (same)]

Sorry, for bad image quality.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to see the white deposits clearly, they're not in focus, but the most likely explanation is a mealybug infestation, particularly if there's any stickiness anywhere on the leaves or stems. Repeated neem oil treatments should help - because its an edible plant, I wouldn't recommend a proper pesticide spray. If, after checking pictures of mealybug infection, you don't think it's that, please post a clearer picture, confirm whether the plant is growing indoors, and what part of the world you're in in case there are other pests local to your area.